# How to disable click on dates

Tags: android

I want to disable click on the dates that are not in the currentweekdays of the month. Im using the caldroid calendar please help me thankyou!

```
final CaldroidListener listenerq = new CaldroidListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
              //Here all dates is being selected.
              //I only want to enable click for the currentweekdays of the month.

        }
```

please see the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCjzY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Why you don't use this code?

```
public void setDisableDates(ArrayList<Date> disableDateList);
public void setDisableDatesFromString(ArrayList<String> disableDateStrings);
public void setDisableDatesFromString(ArrayList<String> disableDateStrings, String dateFormat);
```

Comment: When i tried that, it disable dates but not the date i wanted to. Can you give me suggestion how can i disable dates that are not in the currentmonth? Thankyou.

Comment: Sorry. Just set white background  to view in adapter. For example: In CaldroidGridAdapter look on customizeTextView function. 
Here you should set Background and replace it to the end of function: 
if (dateTime.getMonth() != month) { cellView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.caldroid_darker_gray));  }